# Not sure what .listen() in refluxjs does exactly

Tags: node.js, refluxjs

In `refluxjs` I'm not sure what `.listen()` does. From my understanding, it has the same concepts as nodejs eventemitter but reflux wraps in its own way. I can't seem to find documentation on this anywhere. Maybe I missed it. I would like to find `.listen()` in the source code or documentation so I know exactly how `refluxjs` uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the README? There's a whole section on it: [Listening to changes in data store](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#listening-to-changes-in-data-store).

> #### Listening to changes in data store
>
> In your component, register to listen to changes in your data store
>   like this:
>
> ```js
> // Fairly simple view component that outputs to console
> function ConsoleComponent() {
>
>     // Registers a console logging callback to the statusStore updates
>     statusStore.listen(function(status) {
>         console.log('status: ', status);
>     });
> };
>
> var consoleComponent = new ConsoleComponent();
> ```
>
> Invoke actions as if they were functions:
>
> ```js
> statusUpdate(true);
> statusUpdate(false);
> ```
>
> With the setup above this will output the following in the console:
>
> ```
> status:  ONLINE
> status:  OFFLINE
> ```

And yes, its semantics are pretty much like EventEmitter; it uses [eventemitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) [under the hood](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/blob/df57d9ba4c9e473813266ca13acf66167947568d/src/utils.js#L35). `listen` itself is defined in [`PublisherMethods.js`](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/blob/e0e09bdc186cec34c2268d1a739215b1b49663f6/src/PublisherMethods.js).